# Obtaining index from the Joptionpane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I want to access the index of the option selected by the user.Eg, in the figure below,if i choose microsoft option then it should give me the index 1.Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Similar question seems to be already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074478/how-to-select-an-index-value-from-a-string-array-in-a-joptionpane

Answer (score 2):

Well you get `"Microsoft"` (well the `Object` showing Microsoft at least) as the return value from the show call, is that good enough?

If you need the index just find the index of that return value in the input array you provided to the dialog.

See the input section of the java tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input

Assuming you are using showInputDialog(..):

```
Object[] possibilities = {"Broadcom...", "Microsoft"};
Object result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( frame, "Capture Interfaces", "Input",   JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, icon, possibilities, possibilities[0]);

if (result != null) {
    //result is the choosen object, if you need the index even so:
    int index = 0;
    for (Object o : possibilities) {
        if (result == o)
            break;
        index++
    }
    //index is now the index...
}
```